# NSNumber intValue giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsnumber

I have an NSNumber being passed to be via a 3rd party API, and when I call intValue on the index I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
-(CPFill *) barFillForBarPlot:(CPBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSNumber *)index; 
{
    NSLog(@"bar index %i", index);
    int value = [index intValue];
}
```

The output I get in the debugger is:

bar index 0

bar index 1

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

What the heck is going on?

I have noticed that the first time the method is called, index is **nil** but the next time its obviously not...

How can I debug this?!?! Its such a trivial thing, but I cant seem to fix it!

Comment: hummm, looks like something wrong for me. how can you log an object with     NSLog(@"bar index %i", index);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google turns up [a framework](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Floghound-core-plot.googlecode.com%2Fhg%2Fframework%2FSource%2FCPBarPlot.m%3Fr%3D390825240e2a346c163c5f5f9f0fa1279385c9fd&ei=aLVHTM3sEpC4sQOwhfH9CA&usg=AFQjCNEZka3RgzCoTaw2UAPzLUyaXKwAYA) that appears to call this method with an `NSUInteger` as the argument. Assuming this is the library in question, you're incorrectly typing the argument as an `NSNumber*`. When you think you see `nil` for the index, you're actually just seeing the index 0.

Comment: yes, nice work Chuck, I copied and pasted the code i was using from a sample implementation or core-plot, which I did not test (assumed it worked)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem either something is wrong with the API, or you've used the wrong method signature.  Is index supposed to be a primitive type, like NSInteger?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `%@` for printing `index`, since `index` is an object.  Or, `%d` with `[index intValue]`.

```
-(CPFill *) barFillForBarPlot:(CPBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSNumber *)index 
{
    NSLog(@"bar index %@", index);
    //or NSLog(@"bar index %d", [index intValue]);
    int value = [index intValue];
}
```

**Edit: btw, you have a semicolon at the end of your method heading**

Comment: A semicolon is allowed before the method body, presumably to allow copying and pasting from headers.